# UIDatepicker display future years with ' ---'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

iOS UIDatepicker shows '---' for future years. How to achive this in iOS. It will show only till current year and after that it shows '---'. I seen this when we adding any contact in our iPhone contact app, where there is field to addBirth. You can see that.
Please see screen shot.

[image]

Comment: [`maximumDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615999-maximumdate) might be what you need.

Comment: @Sweeper, that will not help me. I tried that one.

Answer (score 0):

The [`UIDatePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker) doesn't have option for this.

Available Picker modes: [time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/mode/time), [date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/mode/date), [dateAndTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/mode/dateandtime), [countDownTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/mode/countdowntimer).

You can set [maximumDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615999-maximumdate) value, so that date after that can't be selected using UIDatePicker.

If you need to fulfil the exact need, you have to create custom [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) with multiple component and Manage all things. NB: This could be messy.

Comment: Thanks your reply. How apple did for the contact app. Do you think apple customise his library it self ?

Comment: Actually that picker has Optional year selector. I don't this feature is not available on Public API.

Comment: If they created means, something is their to implement like that.

Comment: Finally, in created my own picker like that. @Lal Krishna, thanks for ur suggestion .

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can make it open-source lib if you are interested. :-]

Comment: Sure, i will do that .